# Code Promotion in Jenkins

Tags: deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration

Is there a way in Jenkins to promote the code from Dev to Staging/Prod by writing a job automatically instead of the manual promotions.

What is this feature called if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) does allow for both manual and automatic promotion.

Comment: Do we need to write a script for the same.

Comment: You can write a script, or have the promotion use a plugin like the Deploy plugin. It is up to you.